# Convert PSD side margin to HTML/Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, measurement, psd

I have a PSD file which I want to make into HTML. I want to know how to measure how far elements are from the side of the page (so measuring the margin).

I use the ruler of Photoshop which is in pix but when I enter the same pix number to my html code it seems to be a different size!

I have looked everywhere but no one actually explains how the measurement should be done! Any idea?

Comment: You should not use fixed values for spacing. Because it may looks nice in your screen, but not it other screens with other sizes. Instead use position absolute or floating elements.

Comment: are you saying that i should use % instead of pixels for margins?

Comment: Not exactly. Please read some articles about responsive design and CSS media-queries.

Comment: If you could add some screenshots and also the PSD document settings that would really help eliminate some standard issues.

Answer (score 1):

If your PSD was created with a 72 resolution then the pixels should match up otherwise you will have to adjust based on what resolution you designed the PSD at